# .Net C# DateTime on Mac OSX vs Debian Linux

Tags: c#, linux, macos, datetime, timezone

I have code that converts long numbers to dates.

```
 DateTimeOffset value =
   DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1597325462);
   DateTime showTime = value.DateTime;
   string easternZoneId = "America/New_York";
   TimeZoneInfo easternZone =
       TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(easternZoneId);
   DateTime targetTime =
       TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(showTime, easternZone);
   Console.WriteLine("DateTime is {0}", targetTime);
```

On my Mac, the output is `"DateTime is 8/13/2020 6:31:02 AM"`
On my server the output is `"DateTime is 8/13/2020 9:31:02 AM"`

Identical code on both.

The Linux box value is accurate.  How can I get the same result on my Mac?

Comment: UTC, that's "2020-08-13T13:31:02+00:00" , just to get on the same page. Can you somehow test, whether both systems resolve the same `TimeZoneInfo` ?

Comment: The problem is they don't and I don't know how to work around this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The overload of `TimeZone.ConvertTime` you're using takes a `DateTime` value and a destination `TimeZoneInfo`.  There's no mention of the source time zone, so it is infered from the `.Kind` property of the `DateTime` being passed in.

In your case, that is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, because the `.DateTime` property of a `DateTimeOffset` always returns unspecified, regardless of what the offset is.

In the `ConvertTime` call, if the kind is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, it is assumed to be *local time* (as if it were `DateTimeKind.Local`).  (Scroll down to the Remarks section [in the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime#System_TimeZoneInfo_ConvertTime_System_DateTime_System_TimeZoneInfo_).)  Thus, you are converting as if the Unix timestamp were local-time based, rather than the actuality that it is UTC based.  You get different results between your workstation and server because they have different system-local time zones - not because they are running different operating systems.

There are a number of different ways to rewrite this to address the problem.  I will give you a few to choose from, in order of my preference:

- You could leave everything as a `DateTimeOffset` throughout the conversion process:

  ```
  DateTimeOffset value = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1597325462);
  string easternZoneId = "America/New_York";
  TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(easternZoneId);
  DateTimeOffset targetTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(value, easternZone);
  ```
- You could use the `.UtcDateTime` property instead of the `.DateTime` property:

  ```
  DateTimeOffset value = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1597325462);
  DateTime showTime = value.UtcDateTime;
  string easternZoneId = "America/New_York";
  TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(easternZoneId);
  DateTime targetTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(showTime, easternZone);
  ```
- You could use `ConvertTimeFromUtc` instead of `ConvertTime`:

  ```
  DateTimeOffset value = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1597325462);
  DateTime showTime = value.DateTime;
  string easternZoneId = "America/New_York";
  TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(easternZoneId);
  DateTime targetTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(showTime, easternZone);
  ```
- You could specify UTC as the source time zone in the `ConvertTime` call:

  ```
  DateTimeOffset value = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1597325462);
  DateTime showTime = value.DateTime;
  string easternZoneId = "America/New_York";
  TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(easternZoneId);
  DateTime targetTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(showTime, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, easternZone);
  ```

There are a few other options, such as explicitly setting the kind, but I think the above gives you enough to go on.

If in doubt, pick the first option.  `DateTimeOffset` is much easier to rationalize than `DateTime` in most cases.

Comment: Also, if you needed to support Windows systems, you'd either need to branch to use `"Eastern Standard Time"`, or use `GetTimeZoneInfo` from my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library which does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that there is not such a timezone I'd in the ICU library that both OS look into.

Check the example in the Microsoft docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid?view=netcore-3.1

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("New York: {0}", 
            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Eastern Standard Time"));
```

So it looks like the id you should look for is ""Eastern Standard Time"

If you can't find it then run the following code to check the available timezones on your pc

```
foreach (TimeZoneInfo z in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
                Console.WriteLine(z.Id);
```

> The destinationTimeZoneId parameter must correspond exactly to the time zone's identifier in length, but not in case, for a successful match to occur; that is, the comparison of destinationTimeZoneId with time zone identifiers is case-insensitive.

So check the timezones and copy the correct string to use based on what exists on the machine.

Comment: Both machines have the "America/New_York" timezone and neither has "Eastern Standard Time"

Comment: Good guess, but this isn't the problem at hand.  Feel free to delete this to avoid legitimate "this is not useful" downvotes.